# How do I programmatically change the size a UIImageView that was created on storyboard with autolayout?

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, storyboard

I have an outlet to a UIImageView hooked up from my storyboard to my header file. I am trying to alter the frame of the UIImageView programmatically from my implementation file. I have done the following:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
        if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
            someImageView.frame = CGRectMake(someImageView.frame.origin.x, someImageView.frame.origin.y, someImageView.frame.size.width - 50, someImageView.frame.size.height - 50);
    }
}
```

No matter what I change my width and height to it doesn't seem to change. Could it be that I am using autolayout and have constraints hooked up to the imageView? If so, how do I override these to change the image view's height and width?

Is there a simpler way to do this just from the storyboard?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to reevaluate the constraints you set up in IB. Make sure you don't have width or height constraints, but instead top/bottom/leading/trailing constraints. Then you probably don't have to do anything programmatically. But if you must resize programmatically, create `IBOutlet` references to the constraints in the storyboard, and then you can adjust the `constant` property of the constraint. But don't attempt to change the `frame` if you're using constraints.